# Fastest Way to Split Data Frame by Group, shuffle single vector in R

Tags: r, split-apply-combine

I am familiar with some of the split-apply-combine functions in R, like ddply, but I am unsure how to split a data frame, modify a single variable within each subset, and then recombine the subsets. I can do this manually, but there is surely a better way.

In my example, I am trying to shuffle a single variable (but none of the others) *within a group*. This is for a permutation analysis, so I am doing it many many times, and would thus like to speed things up.

```
allS <- split(all, f=all$cp)
for(j in 1:length(allS)){
    allS[[j]]$party <- sample(x=allS[[j]]$party)
}
tmpAll <- rbind.fill(allS)
```

Sample data frame:

```
all <- data.frame(cp=factor(1:5), party=rep(c("A","B","C","D"), 5))
```

Thanks for any direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(all)`), grouped by 'cp', `sample` the 'party' and assign (`:=`) that output back to the 'party' column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(all)[, party:= sample(party) , by = cp]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `dplyr` way.

```
library(dplyr)
all %>% group_by(cp) %>% mutate(party=sample(party))
```